# Cannot resolve ActivityTestRule after upgrading dependencies. Unable to import ActivityTestRule

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation, test-runner

I have written instrumentation tests which was working fine, but now getting error cannot resolve ActivityTestRule error after upgrading dependencies to

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

I am using android support version 27.1.1

It is working fine with dependencies

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In the most recent update of the Testing Support Library (2018-04-24), the "rules" dependency was apparently removed from the `espresso-core`. I'm not sure why this was done, but [the release notes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/release-notes#espresso_302_runner_102_rules_102_monitor_102_androidtestorchestrator_102_2018_04_24) say this about the change:

> Fixed espresso-core POM file to not pull in "rules" dependency, instead have espresso-intents POM pull it. This should be a NoOp change for developers since espresso-intents cannot be used without espresso-core.

You can fix this problem by adding the following [dependency](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/packages) to `app/build.gradle`:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
```

Comment: Notice how the `support.test:rules` is not an Espresso dependency. It can now be used standalone. Also `core` suggests minimal dependency impact, I don't think it actually used any classes from `rules`. More control for us devs.

Answer (score 1):

AndroidX Test includes another API,**ActivityScenario** that is currently in beta. This API works in a variety of testing environments and provides thread safety within the tests that use it.  Consider using **ActivityScenarioRule** or **ActivityScenario** instead.

```
import androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule

ActivityScenarioRule(YourActivity::class.java)
```