# Can't resolve symbol 'ActivityTestRule'

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm learn to use espresso to test my app, but `ActivityTestRule` always can't be resolved. Here is my app/build.gradle config, and I'm sure that I put test classes at src/androidTest.

Many thanks for help!!

[image]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.teatime"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    // Testing-only dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
}
```

Comment: check your imports check if this is added. 
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;

Comment: Answer by GParekar works but we should not have to downgrade the dependencies. There is a better solution and explanation at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50070152/480269

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I hope this will work for you.

Use

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

Instead

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
```

Comment: I would suggest adding `androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'` instead of downgrading the library versions; that's where the ActivityTestRule class resides now...

Comment: `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'` for AndroidX

Answer (score 0):

Add `import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;` in your imports and then clean and rebuild your app.